# Location based messaging

Tags: android

Im doing a project on location based services, in which i have the following conditions
Set Location manually ( With a radius )

On reaching that location i need to trigger SMS activity

please tell how to go about doing this.

Comment: Step 1: set location with radius. Step 2: Check if you are inside that area. Step 3: Send SMS. Do you have any specific questions?

Answer (score 2):

Now it's much simpler to implement scenarios like this using existing solutions.

For example using Matchmore Kotlin SDK (https://github.com/matchmore/alps-android-sdk)

You could easily create a messeage using their publication:

```
val publication = Publication("LocationBasedChat", 60.0, 1000.0)
publication.properties = hashMapOf("msg" to "message you want to broadcast")
createPublication(publication, { result ->
    Log.i(TAG, "Message created ${result.topic}")
}, Throwable::printStackTrace)
```

plus you could subscribe to any messages around by:

```
val subscription = Subscription("LocationBasedChat", 60.0, 1000.0)
createSubscription(subscription, { result ->
    Log.i(TAG, "Subscription created ${result.topic}")
}, Throwable::printStackTrace)
```

Whenever you receive a match - it means you've got new message to show to user.

```
matchMonitor.addOnMatchListener { matches, _ ->
    Log.i(TAG, "You messages found: ${matches.size}")
}
matchMonitor.startPollingMatches()
```

If you need more they cover plenty of scenarios here
https://matchmore.io/

Answer (score 0):

[Use a Proximity Alert](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#addProximityAlert%28double,%20double,%20float,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29)